# Filter mailing list by country

Tags: mailing

Could you tell me how I can filter a group/mailing list we have to view by certain countries? For example we have a 'Youth Collective' lsit but we'd like to filter this by addresses to see all that are from the UK.

Thanks,
Megan
megan@restlessdevelopment.org

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the advanced search:

Select the group you want to include in the 'Basic Criteria' section and then the country within the 'Address Search'.